# Select multiple images from the sdcard and upload them to a server

Tags: android

My code:

```
protected String doInBackground(HttpResponse... arg0)
{
    String result = "";         
    File file = new File(selectImages);
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String postURL = "http://192.168.1.11/api/review/add_image.php?";
        post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
        totalSize = bin.getContentLength();
        MultiPartEntity reqEntity = new MultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, new ProgressListener()
        {
            public void transferred(long num)
            {
                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
            }
        });

        reqEntity.addPart("userfile", bin);
        post.setEntity(reqEntity); 
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

My result is null.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are you expecting for your result. Since the result comes from your server, what do you send?

Comment: @Knossos if you will done with it please check my question. almost same like this.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164887/how-to-implode-files-in-java

Comment: I suggest you to send the bytes and not the real image btw

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to convert image to base64. So you can send more images in easy way.

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b , Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If you have 5 images you can add them to the array and send it to the server.

Comment: This system could result in the dreaded OutOfMemoryError. Especially if you are sending multiple images, and even more especially if those images happen to be large.

Comment: Yes, right, but you can compress the images.. have you got other solutions?